# Z-index: Materialize select always open in background

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, materialize

so I am using materialize css select to style my dropdowns in a form. When I land on my page, however, the dropdown is always "hidden open". More specifically, if I hover **below** the "residency" dropdown to the white space and even into the later part of the form and I click, it will change the value of the drop down. The only way to get rid of it is if I open the drop down and close it. Why is this occurring?? Any recommendations?

The Z-index of the closed unordered list is 999. When I change it to -1, it goes away but then when I open the drop down, its behind all the other text.

[image]

Comment: With no demo it's hard to say. Maybe you set a css rule that mesh it up?

Answer (score 0):

I have added one more div called **wrapper** and made header and footer position fixed. I have also added the padding in wrapper div as of height of header, same with the case of footer.

Hope this will help

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper" style="overflow-y: auto;overflow-x: hidden;padding-top: 34px;padding-bottom: 126px;">
  <header id='header'>Test 0.1</header>
  <aside id='aside'>
    <p>Menu 1</p>
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    <p>
      <span id='spn'>n</span>
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div id='divMain'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer id='footer'>Address,
    <br>phone,
    <br>etc.
    <br>
    <br>Address,
    <br>phone,
    <br>etc.
    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

header {
      background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

section {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

section div {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

aside {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
}

aside p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

footer {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```